# Access token for anonymous user in django-oauth2-provider

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I have developed an API with Django rest framework and I'm using django-oauth2-provider for OAuth2 access.

In our new design for iOS application, Anonymous User could Like content and we need to create access token without password (I have to create a user based on id that mobile developer generates and he asked for access token without password).

Is it possible to generate access token for anonymous user in django-oauth2-provider?

Comment: Why is that necessary? Souldn't simply putting "AllowAny" in any view's permission classes just work fine?

Comment: @ImanAkbari the functionality could still be gated by some other mechanism, like a special token or time-based feature.